# Azure AppInsights not properly initialized

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-appservice

I have an issue with App Insights for an App Service, it seems to be wrongly initialized.
For the context, I have two app services (test, prod) running .NET api + Angular SPA. Both are deployed the same way, the only difference is the publish configuration (Staging and Release) that only change the Angular app build config.

I setup logging and application insights for my App this way :

```
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
});
builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights(
    config => config.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"),
    _ => { }
);
```

For the test app service, there is no problem, I can access traces in AppInsights -> test-app-insights -> logs -> run query for traces

For the production app service, I have no traces available. The thing is, the code is the same indeed, and I double checked the configuration they seem the same.

However, I saw that my test app has configuration that my production app doesn't have. That configuration is, I assume, generated by app insights.

This is the test app service configuration :

```
[
  {
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
    "value": "<key>",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION",
    "value": "1.0.0",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION",
    "value": "1.0.0",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "value": "<connection-string>",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_ENABLESQLQUERYCOLLECTION",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~2",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~3",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "DISABLE_APPINSIGHTS_SDK",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "IGNORE_APPINSIGHTS_SDK",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_APPINSIGHTS_ENCRYPTEDAPIKEY",
    "value": "{\"ApiKey\":\"<api-key>",\"AppId\":\"<app-id>\"}",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS",
    "value": "30",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
    "value": "recommended",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_PreemptSdk",
    "value": "disabled",
    "slotSetting": true
  }
]
```

This is the production app service configuration :

```
[
  {
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
    "value": "<key>", // double checked the value -> ok
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "value": "<connection-string>", // double checked the value -> ok
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~2", // Was at 3 at the beggining, I tried changing it to two to see if any changes would happen. Did not.
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS",
    "value": "30",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
    "value": "Recommended",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

Indeed, there is a problem with the configuration which, for the test app service, was generated when I deployed the version of my web app with the App Insights configuration update (see .NET code above).

What can be the source of this issue ? What can I double check ?
I also tried restarting the App Service, that did not fix the issue. At the moment I did not try to add the missing configurations manually, as I am not sure about how it will behave as it seems to be generated by App Insights, to avoid any conflicts and also to be sure I will have the right values for the configurations

Please feel free to ask any needed information. I will update the post accordingly
Thanks

Comment: Please share your configuration file.

Comment: I added both test and production settings in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so not sure about how it worked out

I decided to deleted my app insights resources for production, disable app insights on my app service and clean the remaining related configurations.

Then I enabled back again, and it worked just fine. No more configurations issues, no more logs not showing up.

I post this answer so that people can find that possible solution which is, if I didn't just miss it, not showed somewhere on Azure help or so. Indeed, it may depend on if you *can* delete your app insights for business reasons.

Please feel free to add any other advice.